# SQL Incorrect Datetime value for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.....Sometimes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date, sql-update

I'm collecting data from MYSQL db's on different machines via linked servers on MSSQL Server. Once the data has been collected and saved in a table on the main server, i need to update the MYSQL tables with a timestamp, to display when that record was transferred. The code i use is below;

```
UPDATE openquery("server_name", 'SELECT * from tbl_transferinfo') 
SET TransferDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MessageLog = 'Transfer Successful';
```

TransferDate is set as 'datetime'.
The problem is that this runs fine sometimes but other times i get the following error;

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server_name" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.29]Incorrect datetime value: '2020-07-20 13:11:26.1133333' for column 'TransferDate' at row 1".
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server_name" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]".

Any ideas as to why this would be happening more often than not?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have update rights on the accounts you use on the servers showing this issue?

Comment: I believe i should have. It does update the table correctly sometimes. I'm not sure how i would check to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL `datetime` datatype does not accept milliseconds.

You can either change the target column in the MySQL database from `datetime` to `timestamp`, or `cast()` the SQL Server timestamp to remove the milliseconds, like:

```
UPDATE openquery("server_name", 'SELECT * from tbl_transferinfo') 
SET 
    TransferDate = convert(char(19), current_timestamp, 120), 
    MessageLog = 'Transfer Successful';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just tried that and i have the following error pop up;

''NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

I'm using SSMS and maybe that does't use it?? I'm not fluent in the various SQL tools

Comment: According to SSMS, current_timestamp does return datetime

Comment: @jimbonda: I think I initially misread your question. I changed my answer, please have look.

Comment: After changes, this does suggest a better approach - use a pass-through query that can use NOW() and bypass the inter-mixing of sql dialects.

Comment: The change has sorted it. Nice one. Thank you